# reCaptcha said that captcha is wrong (but it's not wrong!)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, recaptcha

I'm using Raspberry Pi with Selenium and PhantomJS. I'm trying to verify the captcha from Google reCaptcha 2.0 but it said that the captcha is not correct (solve more). It always happens to 100% and I've never got a passed captcha from Selenium.

See, as example on this picture:

[image: clicking reCaptcha picture]

Then when I click on "Verify"-Button, then this happend:

[image: reCatpcha Error]

My python code:

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(capcthaframe)
picturetable = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.rc-imageselect-table-3')
images = []

for row in picturetable.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
        for col in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
            images.append(col.find_element_by_tag_name('img'))
if images == []:
        self.fail("Found no captcha images")
        return -1

print "[*] Got answer : " + str(numbers)

for number in numbers:
        index = int(number)-1
        images[index].click()
        print '[+] clicked on image '+str(index+1)

self.driver.save_screenshot('res.png')
time.sleep(1)
verifybutton = self.driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-verify-button')
verifybutton.click()
print "[*] Clicked verify button"
time.sleep(10)
```

I don't think that my code is wrong... So, have anybody a idea what's wrong with this reCaptcha error?

Comment: You are trying to automate CAPTCHA? You obviously do not understand what CAPTCHA is!

Comment: @SiKing No, I'm using 2Captcha for resolving reCaptcha from by human solving. I understand what CAPTCHA is. ;)

Comment: Are you using your own implementation of PhantomJS, or are you using Detro's Ghostdriver? I am guessing Ghostdriver, in which case this might be interesting to you: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#help-needed

Comment: Well I was using special PhantomJS from GitHub for Raspberry Pi (https://github.com/piksel/phantomjs-raspberrypi.git). So, you mean that's the fault why this isn't work? Then I should try other webDriver browser. But PhantomJS was only the one which it was working on Raspberry Pi... :/ Let see.

Comment: It isn't not correct. With each attempt Captcha becomes harder. You just need to solve it twice P.s Sorry for my english)

Comment: Th recapacha2 is making test on the browser, like reneding image on canvas and sending back the rendered image to google in base64. Maybe phantomjs does not pass the test.